# Recognize multiple line comments within a single line with ANTLR4

Tags: parsing, antlr, language-design, antlr4, lexer

I want to parse PostScript code with ANTLR4. I finished with the grammar, but one particular language extension (which was introduced by someone else) makes trouble being reconized.

A short example:

```
1: % This is a line comment
2: % The next line just pushes the value 10 onto the stack
3: 10
4: 
5: %?description This is the special line-comment in question
6: /procedure {
7:   /var1 30 def %This just creates a variable
8:   /var2 10 def %?description A description associated with var2 %?default 20
9:   /var3 (a string value) def %?description I am even allowed to use % signs %?default (another value)
10: }
```

Recognizing line-comments, such as in line 1, 2 and 7 can be done with the Lexer-Rules

```
LINE_COMMENT: '%' .*? NEWLINE;
NEWLINE: '\r'? '\n';
```

which simply match everything after a % until the end of the line.

The problem I have is with those special line-comments, that start with something like `%?description` or `%?default`, because those should be recognized as well, but in contrast to LINE_COMMENT, one can put multiple of those in a single line (such as in lines 8 and 9). So line 8 contains two special comments `%?description A description associated with var2` and `%?default 20`.

Think of it as something like this (although this won't work):

```
SPECIAL_COMMENT: '%?' .*? (SPECIAL_COMMENT|NEWLINE);
```

Now comes the really tricky part: You should be allowed to put arbitrary text after `%?description` including `%` while still being able to split the individual comments.

So in short, the issue can be reduced to splitting a line of the form

```
(%?<keyword> <content with % allowed in it>)+ NEWLINE
```

e.g.

```
%?description descr. with % in in %?default (my default value for 100%) %?rest more
```

into

```
1.) %?description descr. with % in in 
2.) %?default (my default value for 100%)
3.) %?rest more
```

Any ideas, how to formulate Lexer or Parser-rules to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given those rules, I think you'll have to use a predicate in the lexer to check the input stream for occurrences of `%?`. You'll also have to make sure a normal comment must start with a `%`, but not followed by a `?` (or line break char).

Given the grammar:

```
grammar T;

@lexer::members {
  boolean ahead(String text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
      if (text.charAt(i) != _input.LA(i + 1)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}

parse
 : token* EOF
 ;

token
 : t=SPECIAL_COMMENT {System.out.println("special : " + $t.getText());}
 | t=COMMENT         {System.out.println("normal  : " + $t.getText());}
 ;

SPECIAL_COMMENT
 : '%?' ( {!ahead("%?")}? ~[\r\n] )*
 ;

COMMENT
 : '%' ( ~[?\r\n] ~[\r\n]* )?
 ;

SPACES
 : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
 ;
```

which can be tested as follows:

```java
String source = "% normal comment\n" +
    "%?description I am even allowed to use % signs %?default (another value)\n" +
    "% another normal comment (without a line break!)";
TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(source));
TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
parser.parse();
```

and will print the following:

```
normal  : % normal comment
special : %?description I am even allowed to use % signs 
special : %?default (another value)
normal  : % another normal comment (without a line break!)
```

The part `( {!ahead("%?")}? ~[\r\n] )*` can be read as follows: *if there's no "%?" ahead, match any char other than `\r` and `\n`, and do this zero or more times*.